# how to manage http connection in android phone?

Tags: android

I have a problem when i post image on server through phone then my connection is break down. and through emulator it is going perfectly.

I don"t know why this is happening. Can any one suggest me.

### Here is my code

```
     public static HttpResponse postDataOnUrl(String url, String jsonString) {
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            
            HttpHandler handler = HttpHandler.getInstance();
            HttpClient httpclient = handler.getHttpClient();
            BasicCookieStore cookieStore = handler.getBasicCookieStore();
            HttpContext httpContext = handler.getHttpContext();
            httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            System.out.println("=== json string is in :" +jsonString);
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonString);
            entity.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            response = httpclient.execute(httppost, httpContext);
            System.out.println("=== response as url :" + response.toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            response = null;
            System.out
                    .println("Exception in postDataOnUrl(String url, JSONObject obj) : "
                            + ex);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

this code is my connection code and code is break in httpclient

### This code is my save data code

```
View tmpView = imglayout.getChildAt(h);

if (tmpView instanceof ImageView) 
{
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) tmpView;

    Object imgPath = imgView.getTag();
    System.out
            .println("=== fullupload image for imgPath:"
                    + imgPath);
    if (imgPath != null) {
        String fulluploadimgpath = imgView
                .getTag().toString();
        System.out
                .println("=== fullupload image for 1:"
                        + fulluploadimgpath);
        String base64String = Utility
                .getBase64String(fulluploadimgpath);
        System.out
                .println("=== base64String is in :"
                        + base64String);

        if (base64String != null) {

            JSONObject postImageData = new JSONObject();

            postImageData.put("media",
                    base64String);

            HttpResponse imgPostResponse = Utility
                    .postDataOnUrl(
                            Utility.getBaseUrl()
                                    + "user/upload",
                            postImageData
                                    .toString());
            System.out
                    .println("=== fullupload image for imgPostResponse:"
                            + imgPostResponse);

            if (imgPostResponse != null) {

                String imgResponse = Utility
                        .readUrlResponseAsString(imgPostResponse);
                System.out
                        .println("=== imgResponse is in imgResponse :"
                                + imgResponse);

                if (imgResponse != null
                        || imgResponse
                                .trim()
                                .length() != 0) {
                    JSONObject jResObj = new JSONObject(
                            imgResponse);
                    if (jResObj
                            .getBoolean("rc")) {
                        obj.put(hidobj.getReceiveAs(),jResObj.getString("ident"));
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an Exception?

Comment: no i m not getting any kind of exception my problem is when response = httpclient.execute() linecome then before this line execution

Comment: HttpResponse imgPostResponse = Utility
                    .postDataOnUrl(
                            Utility.getBaseUrl()
                                    + "user/upload",
                            postImageData
                                    .toString());
            System.out
                    .println("=== fullupload image for imgPostResponse:"
                            + imgPostResponse);

Comment: this line is execute due to this process my image is not get

Comment: are you sure you use the correct URL? try to log what `Utility.getBaseUrl()` returns

Comment: yes it return correct url and through emulator code is running correctly and image is also posting on server. but through device it is not